# Running Selenium in Azure Function

Tags: azure, selenium, phantomjs, azure-functions

I want to periodically scrape a website with Selenium and a headless PhantomJS driver.
My boss wants me to run it "in the cloud" for reasons, and a serverless Azure Function looks like it could be a useful way to do it, instead of having to run a VM or something.

I've got my VS.net code to do the scraping mostly done, but I just realized that I'm not sure if I can actually deploy it as a function, since it looks like it wants me to include the phantomjs.exe in my project in order to run, which may not work in a Azure Function...

Can I do what I wanted to do, or should I explore other options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PhantomJS is a known unsupported framework in App Service, which is the same environment Azure Functions runs on.

You can find more information here: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#unsupported-frameworks

Comment: OK, good info. Do you know if any of the [other headless browsers](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers) might work? Or any other platform besides Azure Functions that might do what my boss wants? Just asking so if it has to be run locally I can say I did all my homework and it's the only option.

Comment: You should containerize your App and run it in Azure Service Fabric for instance.

Comment: I am trying to do the same. Did you manage to get it working?

Comment: @johnstaveley Sorry, no. Shortly after asking the question they decided that running it locally wasn't that big of a deal, then shortly after I got it all set up to run locally they decided just to scrap the whole thing. It's fine though. I ended up using a lot of the stuff I learned to set up a CEFSharp browser as an alternative to IE. It's not perfect, has a lot less functionality out of the box, and scraping data using javascript is a pain to set up compared to IE, but it gets the job done.

Comment: I am working on a same thing, I am able to run it locally, azure function triggers the console app which ultimately runs selenium bot but It seems it fails when I publish it to azure functions. Any luck with you? What other services from azure would you recommend that could help me achieve the task?

Comment: @JamshaidK. i am facing the same issue, have to start a scrapper with a selenium driver. If the requirement is to have it in the cloud, than the smallest and the cheapest VPS should work well, deployment could be done with a docker image, price will be ~5$ per month, much cheaper than using premium tier of Azure

Comment: @AndreyMazur, Indeed. But the problem is, when it comes to handling concurrent request, you might need a good machine to perform it faster. My case was, I had to allow multiple users triggering the bot which had to fill some forms, submit, retrieve the results while completing captcha challenges as well. This required more processing power, so cheapest VPS might not work very well in this scenario. I had used Azure VM.